# concurrent.futures ThreadPoolExecutor - number of threads does not match

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures and the number of threads does not match.

code:

```
numCPU = cpu_count()
chunks = [a, b, c, d]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=numCPU) as pool:
    pool.map(f, chunks)
```

is spawning up to 8 threads, as obserwed with `htop` and `ps -T -p`  instead of 4, as `print numCpu` yields in `4`

```
~$ ps -T -p 10830
  PID  SPID TTY          TIME CMD
10830 10830 tty2     00:00:00 python3.6
10830 10838 tty2     00:00:00 python3.6
10830 10839 tty2     00:00:00 python3.6
10830 10840 tty2     00:00:00 python3.6
10830 10841 tty2     00:00:01 python3.6
10830 10842 tty2     00:00:04 python3.6
10830 10843 tty2     00:00:05 python3.6
10830 10844 tty2     00:00:02 python3.6
```

I expect 4... why I got 8 threads?

Comment: What OS is this?  On my system (MacOS), it spawns only the number of threads requested (so in your case if numCPU is 4, the total number of threads should be 5, because the original interpreter thread continues running).

Comment: `"Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"` I am not sure if I guess right but half of 8 threads have `00:00:00 TIME` like it is spawned but not really executing?

Comment: More to the point, what _Python_ is this? You should expect to see _at least_ five threads because it started with one, and you asked it to create four more. But the Python interpreter might create other threads that you don't know about. If you are using JPython, for example, that runs in a JVM, and a typical JVM creates several threads that do not execute application code.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: It is `python3.6` which I'm pretty sure is not a JPython or anything else weird, just regular CPython.  Still, yours is a valid point to consider.

Comment: its `Python 3.6.8` and yes the command `ps -T -p 10830` is suppose to print all threads of parent process `10830`. Still i got 8 instead of 4 child threads (parent 10830)